# Haskell High Order Functions, Function Declaration

Tags: function, haskell, type-declaration

I am studying for an exam and I'm confused at this function. Based on the output how do I know that the type declaration of the function is (a -> b -> c)? also, how I can evaluate my function?

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' _ [] _ = []
zipWith' _ _ [] = []
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

What I understand is that high order functions in haskell mean that they take a function as a parameter and return a function as well, right? how can I call this particular function?

I did this:

```
zipWith' [1..5] ['a','z','r']
```

but I know is wrong because I am calling it as if it were the regular `zip` function that takes 2 lists and returns a tuple. I am just confused at the type declaration

`zipWith' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`

Comment: No-one said a higher-order function has to return a function. The term is a somewhat loose one, but usually means a function that *either* has a function as a parameter *or* returns one. `zipWith` takes a function as a parameter and thus is considered a higher-order function - but it certainly doesn't return a function.

Comment: As for how to call `zipWith` (or your, equivalent, version `zipWith\``), you haven't supplied it with the function argument. Try, for example, `zipWith' (+) [1,2] [3,4]` (should be `[4,6]`).

Comment: @RobinZigmond Well, technically it *does* return a function. It takes a `a -> b-> c`, and returns a `[a] -> [b] -> [c]`.

Comment: @wwww Where do you get `[a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`? That is, indeed, the type of `zip`, but it is also the type of `zipWith' (,)` (which is `zipWith'` applied to `(,) :: a -> b -> (a,b)`).

Comment: @chepner - that's true of course. I'm ignoring currying for the purposes of this discussion and assuming we have true "functions of multiple arguments".

Comment: Note that `a ->  b -> c` is , itself, the broadest possible type for a higher-order function. It accepts an argument of some type `a` (which may or may not itself be a function), and returns a function of type `b -> c`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I think for this question, one actually *should* explicitly acknowledge currying. It helps explain why the first argument has to have type `a -> b -> c` instead of just `a -> b`.

Comment: @wwww you call it as `zipWith' (+) [1..22] [3..33]` or `zipWith' (,) [1..22] "Hello, world!"` etc.

Answer (score 2):

For this answer, we'll acknowledge that all functions are curried. That is, every function has a type `a -> b`, where `a` and `b` are some type.

---

A higher-order function is one whose type includes a function for *either* its argument *or* return type. Return values are easy: it's any function you ordinary think of as taking more than one argument:

- `take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`. It takes an `Int` and returns a (polymorphic) function that takes a list and returns a list.
- `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. It takes a function (literally *any* function) and returns a function from lists to lists. The types of the return value is determined by the type of the argument.

Higher-order functions that take an function and return something that isn't a function are actually somewhat rare. Perhaps a commenter will point out an obvious one I am overlooking, but until then, consider `fix :: (a -> a) -> a`.

Now, `zipWith'` is an example of a higher-order function whose argument *itself* must be a higher-order function. The general type `a -> b` can unify with an ordinary function like `ord :: Char -> Int` (`a ~ Char` and `b ~ Int`) as well as a higher-order function like `(+)` (with `a ~ Num t => t` and `b ~ Num t => t -> t`. The type `a -> b -> c` will *only* unify with higher-order functions. `a` may or may not be a function type, but `b -> c` is an explicit function type.

This means that once you apply `zipWith'` to some higher-order function, type inference gives you more information about what the types of `[a]`, `[b]`, and `[c]` must be in the resulting function.

- `zipWith' (+)` tells you that `a ~ b ~ c ~ Num t => [t]`.
- `zipWith' (,)` tells you that `a` and `b` are still unrestricted, but `c ~ (a, b)`
- `zipWith' (:)` tells you that `a` is unrestricted, but `b ~ c ~ [a]`.

It may also help if you consider that `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]` could be defined as `zip = zipWith' (,)`.

Comment: A glance at Hoogle suggests eg. mtl `gets` , `asks` for `(a->b)->c` type functions, though I concede this is a little bit cheating.